# Creating Picture Gallery with java API problem

Tags: java, api

I want to create a galery of picture so I find problem when I press the previous or next button to show the next/previous picture :

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String t [] = new String[3];
    int i = 0;
    t[0] = "2.JPG";
    t[1] = "1.JPG";
    t[2] = "3.PNG";

    try {
        File f = new File(t[i]);
        Image img = ImageIO.read(f);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        imgspace.setIcon(icon);
        i = i + 1;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        showMessageDialog(null, "Nothing happen");
    }
}
```

Just the output is one image when I press the button.

Comment: i shall be somehow static

Comment: how ? i didn't understand

Comment: Your "i" variable, should be "static", google for "static" variable in java to get the point